# styles and js not found 404 magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

I installed magento2 on openserver
created my custom theme
developer mode is enabled
content deployed
When i try to load home page browser showed errors [image]

in pub/static i have only **wNumb.min.js and other files** and server cant load them.

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are used your language incited of default language. thus you have to deploy your language like this

remove content of **pub/static/***

Remove **var** folder.

Run this command for deploy current language

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_CH

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

I hope this will help for you.

Comment: nothing changed
after made deploy  generated min.js files but browser want to load without "min"
and returned 404

Comment: have you set `permission` after `static deploy`?

Comment: what does it mean? Can you explain wich folder or file?